# How can I read scrolls on an open modal window?

Tags: javascript, scroll, modal-dialog

1. I have a fullscreen scrollable modal window.
2. How can I read pixels scrolled (to add some interactive things)?

scrollY on the element won't work.

Comment: Please post your code adhering to the [**minimal, complete and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks!

Comment: Cause it works for 'window' only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Element's `scrollTop` (the number of pixels the content of an element is scrolled vertically)

```css
.modal{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 15%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
<div class="modal" id="modal">
Header
<span style="position: relative; top: 500px;">Footer</span>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("modal").onscroll = function (e) {
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = "Number of pixels scrolled vertically: "+document.getElementById("modal").scrollTop; 
};
</script>
```

Comment: @OctaviusAugust No problem.